# Is it possible to complete this request without join and union?

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume there is a table a and its content is:

```
col1   col2
a      1
b      2
c      2
d      1
e      1
```

Now, is it possible to write one `select..from..` **without** `join` or `union` to get amount of 1 in col2 / amount of all elements in col1 (in this case, 3/5)?

I'm using ORACLE. Any help is appreciated.

---

Sorry I did not put a proper example at the beginning..the elements in col1 are not same..

Comment: So the only thing you want to be returned is "3, 5", or 0.6? Do a GROUP BY. Use a case expression to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  sum(case when col2 = 1 then 1 end) * 1.0 / count(distinct col1)
from    YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with `avg()` and `case`:

```
select avg(case when col2 = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
from t;
```

If you want this for each `col1` value, then throw in a `where` or `group by`:

```
select col1, avg(case when col2 = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
from t
group by col1;
```